# Asking questions and answering them immediately

Tags: discussion

Lately I have seen a number of questions posted on TGO that have been answered immediately by the very same person that was asking the question.

The latest examples...

- [What is a top strap on a revolver?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18234/what-is-a-top-strap-on-a-revolver)
- [How do you make peanut butter less sticky?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-do-you-make-peanut-butter-less-sticky)
- [What are the advantages/disadvantages of octagonal barrels?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18164/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-octagonal-barrels)
  (There are tons more...)

All of the questions were answered by the original question author within minutes of asking the question (sometimes in the very same minute).

I am not sure if this is an ill-advised attempt at farming reputation (I don't assume it is ;)), or the attempt to build up TGO as a catch-all reference guide (which it isn't, and isn't meant to be).

Should such questions be asked at all?

Answer (score 6):

[Self-answering questions is perfectly legitimate, and is in fact encouraged!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) This refers to an important blog post on the subject written by Jeff Atwood, a co-founder (former) of Stack Overflow, entitled "It's OK to Ask and Answer Your own Questions."

From that post:

> To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own
>   question, it is explicitly encouraged.
>
> Bottom line — never hesitate to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site. Please do! It’s all part of our shared mission to make the internet better.

From the [help section of the site](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer):

> ### Can I answer my own question?
>
> **Yes!** Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer
>   their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the
>   answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so
>   that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly
>   okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Liam, I added some more information from the blog post you referenced in your first paragraph, including an additional quote from the same page. My intention was to expand without changing the original intent of your answer. If I over-stepped, I'm really sorry, and hope you'll roll back! Thanks!

Comment: No problem @Sue

Comment: I am totally aware (and agree) that self-answering is ok. But I still hold that someone asking a question _shouldn't be asking if they already know the answer_.

Comment: But that's exactly what the checkbox is for [*"To encourage people to do this, there is a checkbox at the bottom of the page every time you ask a question"*](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). So, again this is explicitly by design.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the questions you brought up,

- I was wondering what a top strap was when I was looking at the black powder revolvers on Cabelas and couldn't find the information in any easily accessible places.
- I have recommended peanut butter at least twice, it seems to reason that I can also recommend a better way of carrying it.
- I am not sure that anyone else would be willing to do the legwork it took to get the answer, and besides, I wanted to avoid people not getting the subtle difference between this question and my previous closed one.

As for why someone would want to self-answer

- It avoids negative remarks by people **insinuating that the OP is dumb/stupid** for not knowing the answer. See the deleted answer [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14853/why-are-carabiners-so-much-weaker-if-the-gate-is-open?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- It keeps the OP from being **accused of not doing their own research** and wanting other people to do it for them.
- Questions were it looks like the OP **could have self-answered attract downvotes.**

  - [Why do some birds fly in a V-formation?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/why-do-some-birds-fly-in-a-v-formation)
  - [How does a European Robin differ from an American Robin?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17184/how-does-a-european-robin-differ-from-an-american-robin)
  - [What is a lava tube, as a place to see bats? Are there any in the United States?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17197/what-is-a-lava-tube-as-a-place-to-see-bats-are-there-any-in-the-united-states)
  - [Why does the Iditarod sled dog race use separate routes in alternating years?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17124/why-does-the-iditarod-sled-dog-race-use-separate-routes-in-alternating-years)
- People don't seem to want to encourage answers by upvoting questions, if **I write something, I am ineligible for over 3% of the possible upvotes** because that's how many I have contributed to the site.

  - [Is the correct term Canada Goose or Canadian Goose or is there a difference?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18146/is-the-correct-term-canada-goose-or-canadian-goose-or-is-there-a-difference)
  - [Carrying a bridge camera while hiking with a backpack](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18072/carrying-a-bridge-camera-while-hiking-with-a-backpack/18075#comment45388_18075)
- Sometimes people close questions because of what they imagine answers to be to broad or unanswerable.

  - [Is this rock I found on the Toiyabe Crest Trail an arrowhead?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17360/is-this-rock-i-found-on-the-toiyabe-crest-trail-an-arrowhead)
- I like answering questions, and yet our question rate hovers at below 2 per day.

  - https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3659/the-great-outdoors
- For a while **someone was downvoting everything I wrote**, asking and answering at the same time helps offset that.
- From a rep only standpoint, today it made the difference between 8 points and 68 points.

Also, what is the difference between **me answering a question before it gets to 5 views which I do fairly often and me answering my own question**?

Finally, I have to say that all of the **unexplained downvotes** on mine and other peoples questions really doesn't make me want to ask questions without answering them in addition to all of the other downsides I listed above.

Answer (score -1):

*(Yes, the irony of answering my very own question here didn't escape me. I wanted to clearly separate the discussion from potential answers though...)*

IMHO questions asked on stack exchange should be [real questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-considered-a-real-question). We allowed hypothetical questions (see [here](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/do-we-really-want-to-ban-hypothetical-questions)), but the instantaneous answering of your own question clearly shows that it wasn't an actual problem that somebody had, nor was it even a hypothetical problem.

To quote the above link on *what makes a question real*:

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect. If you don't like the question or answer then you can downvote it. But there is no reason not to add a self answering question (the system is designed to allow this). Wether or not it is a real question is down to the community to decide (via up or down voting). Similarly if it's off topic you can vote to close.

Comment: The idea of self-answering is if you had a real question and it was hard to find an answer, by asking and answering the question yourself, you are helping the next person.